# Correct backwards-compatible way to migrate to modern attrs/cattrs style?

Tags: python, python-attrs

### Question

I have a set of projects that I wrote starting in early 2020 using attrs v19.3.0 and cattrs for serialization/deserialization.  What is the *correct*, *fully backwards-compatible* way to migrate classes in these projects from the old `@attr.s`/`attr.ib` style to the modern style with `@define` and `@frozen`?

### Explanation of the Problem

My assumption has been that I can mix-and-match old and new style classes, and that there's always a way to get equivalent functionality with the new annotations.  I have been converting one class at a time, checking for unit test failures and MyPy warnings, etc. after each conversion.

I've now moved to the most complicated object hierarchy in this code, which also uses cattrs for serialization/deserialization.  I can't find a backwards-compatible solution.  As soon as I convert even one class in the module, my test suite immediately fails with cattr-related errors.

### Minimal Test Case

I originally showed some of the actual code here, but that was just too confusing to be useful.  I've now narrowed the problem down to a small test case.

Here is the old-style class with `@attr.s` and `attr.ib`.  With this code, the test case passes.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Dict
import attr
import cattrs

converter = cattrs.Converter()

@attr.s
class Game:
    players = attr.ib(type=Dict[str, str])
    def copy(self) -> Game:
        return converter.structure(converter.unstructure(self), Game)

class TestGame:
    def test_copy(self):
        game = Game(players={"key" : "value"})
        copy = game.copy()
        assert copy == game and copy is not game
```

This is the new-style class with the equivalent test case:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Dict
import attrs
import cattrs

converter = cattrs.Converter()

@attrs.define
class Game:
    players: Dict[str, str]
    def copy(self) -> Game:
        return converter.structure(converter.unstructure(self), Game)

class TestGame:
    def test_copy(self):
        game = Game(players={"key" : "value"})
        copy = game.copy()
        assert copy == game and copy is not game
```

This fails with the following error:

```
test_sample.py:15 (TestGame.test_copy)
self = <tests.test_sample.TestGame object at 0x108ab2490>

    def test_copy(self):
        game = Game(players={"key" : "value"})
>       copy = game.copy()

test_sample.py:18: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
test_sample.py:13: in copy
    return converter.structure(converter.unstructure(self), Game)
../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py:281: in structure
    return self._structure_func.dispatch(cl)(obj, cl)
../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py:446: in structure_attrs_fromdict
    conv_obj[name] = self._structure_attribute(a, val)
../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py:422: in _structure_attribute
    return self._structure_func.dispatch(type_)(value, type_)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <cattrs.converters.Converter object at 0x108a9d6d0>, _ = {'key': 'value'}
cl = 'Dict[str, str]'

    def _structure_error(self, _, cl):
        """At the bottom of the condition stack, we explode if we can't handle it."""
        msg = "Unsupported type: {0!r}. Register a structure hook for " "it.".format(cl)
>       raise StructureHandlerNotFoundError(msg, type_=cl)
E       cattrs.errors.StructureHandlerNotFoundError: Unsupported type: 'Dict[str, str]'. Register a structure hook for it.

../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py:344: StructureHandlerNotFoundError
```

It seems like what is happening is that cattrs doesn't understand that the `players` field is a mapping-type field for the new-style class.

Comment: so, whatcha trying to do here?

Comment: @rv.kvetch, not sure I understand the question.  I'm trying to migrate all of the old-style attr.s/attr.ib classes to define and frozen without breaking my test suite. Seems like that should be easy, but apparently not in this case - looking for any suggestions about how to do that migration in a backwards compatible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're hitting [this issue](https://github.com/python-attrs/cattrs/issues/41). There are two ways of resolving it:

1. Don't use `from __future__ import annotations`. Your code becomes:

   ```
   import attrs
   import cattrs

   converter = cattrs.Converter()


   @attrs.define
   class Game:
       players: dict[str, str]

       def copy(self) -> "Game":
           return converter.structure(converter.unstructure(self), Game)


   class TestGame:
       def test_copy(self):
           game = Game(players={"key": "value"})
           copy = game.copy()
           assert copy == game and copy is not game
   ```

   This is ugly and is likly to break in the future in any case.
2. Use [`GenConverter`](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/converters.html#cattr-genconverter) instead of `Converter`:

   ```
   from __future__ import annotations

   import attrs
   import cattrs

   converter = cattrs.GenConverter()


   @attrs.define
   class Game:
       players: dict[str, str]

       def copy(self) -> Game:
           return converter.structure(converter.unstructure(self), Game)


   class TestGame:
       def test_copy(self):
           game = Game(players={"key": "value"})
           copy = game.copy()
           assert copy == game and copy is not game
   ```

   This is probably the correct solution.

Your sample code passes its test with both versions of the code
presented in this answer (when tested under Python 3.10.4).

(You'll note I'm using `dict` here instead of `typing.Dict`; that's just a personal preference and the code works either way.)

Comment: Hey @larsks, I've been working tonight on reproducing a minimal sample that demonstrates the problem.  I originally thought I was asking a simple question - some obviously wrong thing I was missing - but it seems to be more complicated than that.  I'll rework the question tomorrow and hopefully make it more intelligible.

Comment: I've reworked the question with a minimal example.  The behavior seems to have something to do with having a dict on the class, which might explain why you weren't able to reproduce it.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your reproducer.

Comment: Yes, GenConverter seems to have been the missing puzzle piece.  With that one change, I'm able to convert my code as expected.  My test suite passes at GitHub for Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10.   I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  I appreciate your help digging into this.